# ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'XXX.iOS.app/GoogleMaps' is not permitted. ( VS - Xamarin.Forms )

Tags: xcode, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I have come across this error when trying to publish my application, the project is programmed with visual studio 2019 and using xamarin.forms. So I have little experience with XCODE. And many of the solutions they propose are not very clear.

[Message Error in Trasporter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSw0Q.png)

These errors give me when adding the IPA in Transporter, it's been several days now... I've cleaned the solution, deleted the bin and obj folder, updated the nugets package...

[and if I publish from visual studio it only tells me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybu4b.png)

First of all, Thanks

Comment: The messages indicate that you are trying to include google maps executables in your iOS app. As the messages say, that is **not permitted**. What map functionality does your app need? Did you test this first on an iOS simulator? Are you trying to take a solution that works on a desktop computer, and make it work on a mobile device? Need more details about what your app does. **Bottom line:** the fix will involve one or more nugets that are intended for **use on mobile devices**. On iOS, it might be better to use Apple's built-in map support...

Comment: ... **or Mapbox**. If you really want to use google maps, see [Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk).

Comment: What doc or tutorial are you following, to upload a xamarin forms app via Transporter? The only **Transporter** mention I see online is for uploading a **mac** app. Mobile apps (ios or Android) have more limitations than desktop (mac or pc), in what they are permitted to do. For Apple, **ios publishing** isn't via Transporter. See [Publishing Xamarin.iOS apps to the app store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=macos).

Comment: Consider using [Xamarin.Essentials Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/maps?tabs=ios).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve
I need to use the google maps executable to show the map, search for locations and redirect me on the map, marks...
In the simulator it goes perfectly and works correctly
The tutorial I followed to configure google maps

https://xamarinlatino.com/google-maps-f%C3%A1cil-en-xamarin-forms-7b84d474b3f1

the nuget
Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps by amay007

Comment: That looks like it should work. But don’t use Transporter to publish app for iOS. See the Publishing Xamarin.iOS … link in my earlier comment.